# Tap on UIImageView to show the buttons (take a pic/select from album)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have multiple `UIImageView`s.

When the users taps on any of these `UIImageView` items, i want the buttons to scroll up (take a pic, select an existing pic & cancel).

How do i do this?

I do not want these buttons to be seen all the time. only when the user touches or taps on the UIImageView.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
   UIGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedImage:)];
    [myImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    myImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES; // default is no for UIImageView
```

and the action looks something like this:

```
- (void)tappedImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    // do stuff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin. I need to call UIActionsheet when the image is tapped. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Look up [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the doc.
You can attach it to the image view and your method will be called when user tap the imageView..
then you can simply toggle your controls visibility.